# What is a continuous endomorphism of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, continuity, group-homomorphism

I'm familiar with the concept of a endomorphism and automorphism, but I don't know it means for them to be continuous... I have tried searching for a defintion online without any success... Any help defining this will be really appreciated!

Comment: Where did you read / hear this phrase? If a mathematician wrote it then it refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function (on a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group), but if a physicist wrote it it might be a bit different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuity doesn't make sense on just a group. However, many times you have not only group operations but also a *topology* on your group. If this topology is such that the group operation and the inverse operation are both continuous, what we have is called a *topological* group.

Examples of topological groups include $\Bbb R$ with addition and the standard topology, and $S^2$ with rotations and the standard topology.

And once you have a topological group, you can ask whether an automorphism or endomorphism is continuous.